# how to create bottom menus in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-menu

I need of this type of menus like look image bottom.

[image: I need this of menu]

But i found this type of menu.

[image]

and here my menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/weather"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="weather"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="Home"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/java"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="Java"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/android"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="Android"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: read about tabhost and tabactivity

Comment: thanks for comment but where i found this tutorial

Comment: [Bottom TabHost](http://androidcodeblogspot.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-fragment-tab-example-bottom.html)

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/android-child-group-activity-android.html

Comment: @AnandJain Did you solved this issue ?

Comment: No @IntelliJAmiya can u solve this??

Comment: Not yet .but I will trying

Answer (score 0):

you don't need menu, create this with a **Horizontal RecyclerView** and set an onMenuClickListener. just it

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

whit this Listener you can control your button.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: for which par? **recycler** or **menu**?